# How to close button (X) on click?

Tags: javascript, css

I need the code to close the button on click X, can anyone help?

```css
.n102-widget-button-popup-name {
  font: bold 14px"Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #000
}

.n102-widget-button-popup-description {
  margin: 4px 0 0 0;
  font: 13px"Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #424956
}

.n102-widget-button-popup {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  padding: 12px 10px 12px 14px;
  width: 279px;
  border: 2px solid #2fc7f7;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer
}

.n102-widget-button-popup-triangle {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #fff;
  border-right: 2px solid #2fc7f7;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #2fc7f7
}

.n102-widget-button-popup-show {
  display: block;
  -webkit-animation: show .4s linear forwards;
  animation: show .4s linear forwards
}

.n102-widget-button-position-top-left .n102-widget-button-popup-triangle {
  top: 19px;
  left: -6px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(134deg);
  transform: rotate(134deg)
}

.n102-widget-button-position-bottom-left .n102-widget-button-popup-triangle {
  bottom: 25px;
  left: -6px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(134deg);
  transform: rotate(134deg)
}

.n102-widget-button-position-bottom-left .n102-widget-button-popup,
.n102-widget-button-position-bottom-middle .n102-widget-button-popup {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 75px
}

.n102-widget-button-position-bottom-right .n102-widget-button-popup-triangle {
  bottom: 25px;
  right: -6px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg)
}

.n102-widget-button-position-bottom-right .n102-widget-button-popup {
  left: -298px;
  bottom: 0
}

.n102-widget-button-position-top-right .n102-widget-button-popup-triangle {
  top: 19px;
  right: -6px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg)
}

.n102-widget-button-position-top-right .n102-widget-button-popup {
  top: 0;
  left: -320px
}

.n102-widget-button-position-top-middle .n102-widget-button-popup-triangle {
  top: 19px;
  left: -6px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(134deg);
  transform: rotate(134deg)
}

.n102-widget-button-position-top-middle .n102-widget-button-popup,
.n102-widget-button-position-top-left .n102-widget-button-popup {
  top: 0;
  left: 75px
}

.n102-widget-button-position-bottom-middle .n102-widget-button-popup-triangle {
  bottom: 25px;
  left: -6px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(134deg);
  transform: rotate(134deg)
}

.bx-touch .n102-widget-button-popup {
  padding: 10px 22px 10px 15px
}

.bx-touch .n102-widget-button-popup {
  width: 230px
}

.bx-touch .n102-widget-button-position-bottom-left .n102-widget-button-popup {
  bottom: 90px;
  left: 0
}

.bx-touch .n102-widget-button-popup-image {
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto
}

.bx-touch .n102-widget-button-popup-content {
  text-align: center
}

.bx-touch .n102-widget-button-position-bottom-left .n102-widget-button-popup-triangle {
  bottom: -6px;
  left: 25px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg)
}

.bx-touch .n102-widget-button-position-bottom-left .n102-widget-button-popup {
  bottom: 90px;
  left: 0
}

.bx-touch .n102-widget-button-position-bottom-right .n102-widget-button-popup {
  bottom: 90px;
  left: -160px
}

.bx-touch .n102-widget-button-position-bottom-right .n102-widget-button-popup-triangle {
  bottom: -6px;
  right: 30px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg)
}

.bx-touch .n102-widget-button-position-bottom-middle .n102-widget-button-popup {
  bottom: 90px;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%)
}

.bx-touch .n102-widget-button-position-bottom-middle .n102-widget-button-popup-triangle {
  bottom: -6px;
  left: 108px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(134deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg)
}

.bx-touch .n102-widget-button-position-top-middle .n102-widget-button-popup {
  top: 90px;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  transform: translate(-50%, 0)
}

.bx-touch .n102-widget-button-position-top-middle .n102-widget-button-popup-triangle {
  top: -7px;
  left: auto;
  right: 108px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg)
}

.bx-touch .n102-widget-button-position-top-left .n102-widget-button-popup {
  top: 90px;
  left: 0
}

.bx-touch .n102-widget-button-position-top-left .n102-widget-button-popup-triangle {
  left: 25px;
  top: -6px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg)
}

.bx-touch .n102-widget-button-position-top-right .n102-widget-button-popup {
  top: 90px;
  left: -150px
}

.bx-touch .n102-widget-button-position-top-right .n102-widget-button-popup-triangle {
  top: -7px;
  right: 40px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg)
}

.n102-widget-button-popup-btn-hide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  right: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20width%3D%2210%22%20height%3D%2210%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2010%2010%22%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23525C68%22%20fill-rule%3D%22evenodd%22%20d%3D%22M6.41%205.07l2.867-2.864-1.34-1.34L5.07%203.73%202.207.867l-1.34%201.34L3.73%205.07.867%207.938l1.34%201.34L5.07%206.41l2.867%202.867%201.34-1.34L6.41%205.07z%22/%3E%3C/svg%3E');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  opacity: .2;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s;
  transition: opacity .3s;
  cursor: pointer
}

.n102-widget-button-popup-btn-hide:hover {
  opacity: 1
}

.bx-touch .n102-widget-button-popup-btn-hide {
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20width%3D%2214%22%20height%3D%2214%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2014%2014%22%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23525C68%22%20fill-rule%3D%22evenodd%22%20d%3D%22M8.36%207.02l5.34-5.34L12.36.34%207.02%205.68%201.68.34.34%201.68l5.34%205.34-5.34%205.342%201.34%201.34%205.34-5.34%205.34%205.34%201.34-1.34-5.34-5.34z%22/%3E%3C/svg%3E');
  background-repeat: no-repeat
}

.n102-widget-button-popup-inner {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
  /* flex-flow: row wrap */
}

.n102-widget-button-popup-content {
  width: 200px
}

.n102-widget-button-popup-image {
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  width: 42px;
  text-align: center
}

.n102-widget-button-popup-image-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover
}

.n102-widget-button-popup-button {
  margin: 15px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center
}

.n102-widget-button-popup-button-item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 16px 0 0;
  font: bold 12px"Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #08a6d8;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #08a6d8;
  -webkit-transition: border-bottom .3s;
  transition: border-bottom .3s;
  cursor: pointer
}

.n102-widget-button-popup-button-item:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent
}

.n102-widget-button-popup-button-item:last-child {
  margin: 0
}

.n102-widget-button-pulse {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 1px solid #00aeef;
  border-radius: 50%
}
```

```html
<div data-n102-crm-hello-cont="" class="n102-widget-button-popup n102-widget-button-popup-show" style="border-color: #00adf2;">
  <span data-n102-hello-btn-hide="" class="n102-widget-button-popup-btn-hide"></span>
  <div class="n102-widget-button-popup-inner">
    <div class="n102-widget-button-popup-image">
      <span data-n102-hello-icon="" class="n102-widget-button-popup-image-item" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://dcnt5qvi2hv76.cloudfront.net/b3067253/resize_cache/721200/f72cdc32ecc10461003d548dee4468d0/crm/button/495fc22c03e471aaa48ed60d48ba772c.png?h=auto-alliance.bitrix24.ua&quot;);"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="n102-widget-button-popup-content">
      <div data-n102-hello-name="" class="n102-widget-button-popup-name">Шкурлей Анастасія</div>
      <div data-n102-hello-text="" class="n102-widget-button-popup-description">Вітаю! Готова допомогти вам. Напишіть мені, якщо у вас виникнуть запитання.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="n102-widget-button-popup-triangle" style="border-color: #00adf2;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your CSS is not related to the issue. Are you using some frameworks?

Answer (score 1):

You need javascript if you want the interact with the DOM.

Judging from the CSS you can replace `n102-widget-button-popup-show` to
`n102-widget-button-popup-hide` on your OuterMost Div.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the feedback but it still doesn't work, check on https://codepen.io/chu-thi-lan/pen/ExEwmeq

Answer (score 1):

please try this one

```js
var x_btn = document.querySelector('.n102-widget-button-popup-btn-hide')
x_btn.addEventListener('click', function () {this.parentElement.style.display = 'none'});


var popup= document.querySelector('[data-n102-crm-button-cont]');
    var buttonBlock = document.querySelector('[data-n102-crm-button-block]');

    var TurnOn = true;
    
    popup.addEventListener("click", function(){     
      if (TurnOn) {
        popup.classList.add("n102-widget-button-bottom");
      buttonBlock.classList.remove("n102-widget-button-hide");
      buttonBlock.classList.add("n102-widget-button-show");
      TurnOn = false;
      } else {
        popup.classList.remove("n102-widget-button-bottom");
      buttonBlock.classList.add("n102-widget-button-hide");
      buttonBlock.classList.remove("n102-widget-button-show");
      TurnOn = true;
      } 
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, All almost done, but i want it to close only the popup but not the contact button. Check again my code on https://codepen.io/chu-thi-lan/pen/ExEwmeq

Comment: I have changed something in javascript code. I hope it will work

Comment: Good job. This code solved my issue. I appreciate your help, Thank you very much.